# Android MediaScanner in UncaughtExceptionHandler not scanning file

Tags: android, exception, race-condition, android-mediascanner

I have implemented an exception handler in my app which creates a dump file when the app crashes due to an uncaught exception, then hands off to the default exception handler.

The file gets created with the correct contents, but it's not visible on a connected PC unless I manually trigger a media scan. I've added code to trigger a media scan on the new file, as shown below:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            Context c = getApplicationContext();
            File dumpDir = c.getExternalFilesDir(null);
            DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", Locale.ROOT);
            fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String fileName = String.format("dump-%s.log", fmt.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));

            File dumpFile = new File (dumpDir, fileName);
            PrintStream s;
            try {
                InputStream buildInStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.build);
                // write dump
                s.flush();
                s.close();
                String [] scanPaths = {dumpFile.toString()};
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(c, scanPaths, null, null);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    });
```

However, the file still doesn't appear until I manually trigger a full media scan. By inserting log statements I could verify that my code runs all the way to the end, after the media scan gets triggered.

<del>My suspicion is that</del> <del>the actual scan takes part in the same process and thus gets killed as soon as the default exception handler finishes, which may be sooner than the scan completes</del> <del>the app gets killed before the scan completes, and the media scanner aborts tasks if the requesting process no longer exists.</del>

Suspecting that the app gets killed before the scan completes and that the media scanner aborts the scan as a result, I implemented an `OnScanCompletedListener` which sets a flag upon scan completion and wait for that flag to be set. However, that listener never seems to get called.

<del>Is my suspicion correct?</del> What is wrong here? How can I ensure the media scanner gets to scan the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I don't know why exactly the above doesn't work, but sending an `Intent` rather than relying on a `MediaScannerConnection` worked.

Replace

```
String [] scanPaths = {dumpFile.toString()};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(c, scanPaths, null, null);
```

with

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(dumpFile);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
c.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

and the dump file appears instantly after a crash.

Comment: Note: In android 4.2 the scanner can only rescan to whole device while in android-5.0 you can ask the scanner to scan only a certain file. So executing this on an older android whith many files might become a problem. on my android 4.2 tablet i have 17000 photos on sdcard and scanning can take several hours.

Comment: According to the docs, the Intent has been around since API level 1. Does that mean it would trigger a full scan on earlier versions?

Comment: at least on my android-4.2 it triggers a full scan

Comment: `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` broadcast action is deprecated in Android API 32